# how to call php function inside functions.php wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I have a lot of functions in my functions.php and need to call them directly inside functions.php. I did this in this way but admin panel started to work very slowly when am calling functions in this way:

```
function setTumblrShares($tumblrUrl){  
    global $wpdb; 
    $shareTmbArgs = array(
       'posts_per_page' => -1,
       'offset' => 0,
       'order' => 'DESC',
       'orderby'  => 'date',
       'post_type' => 'video', 
       'post_status' => 'publish',
       'suppress_filters' => 0 
   );
   $shareTumblrCountList = get_posts($shareTmbArgs);
   if ($shareTumblrCountList) {
      foreach ($shareTumblrCountList as $shareTumblrCountItem) {
        $tumblrUrl = get_permalink($shareTumblrCountItem->ID); 
        $shareTumbData = getTumblrShares($tumblrUrl);
        $tumblrShares = $shareTumbData["response"]["note_count"]; 
        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "posts";
        $wpdb->update( $table_name, array( 'tumblrShareCount' => $tumblrShares),array('ID'=>$shareTumblrCountItem->ID));
      } 
   }
}
function getTumblrShares($tumblrUrl){  
   $jsonForReddit =  json_decode(file_get_contents("http://api.tumblr.com/v2/share/stats?url=".$tumblrUrl),true);
   return $jsonForReddit;
} 
add_action('admin_menu', 'setTumblrShares');
```

Comment: Effect of WP speed depends on what you called in `myFunction`.

Comment: I updated my question, see it now pls @Raptor

Comment: Try `pre_get_posts` , not tested but still believes it may help you.

Comment: I tried but it gives me an error FATAL ERROR: ALLOWED MEMORY SIZE OF 268435456 BYTES EXHAUSTED (TRIED TO ALLOCATE 523800 BYTES) IN /WP-INCLUDES/QUERY.PHP ON LINE 2389 @PrafullaKumarSahu

Comment: If memory size is the problem, you can increase the size from php.ini file.but can you describe what you are trying to achieve, I do not want to understand it from your code.

Comment: I created admin menu where I am tracking post shares count in different social networks, currently I have 6 social networks so have 6 functions for each tracking but after I added them as add_action('admin_menu', 'myFunction') admin panel started work very very slowly.... @PrafullaKumarSahu

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu OP's memory limit is already set to 256MB, which is reasonable & sufficient.

Comment: First try to do this in a single function using conditional statement and what I can guess you want to save those data in database, can you try this using wp_footer hook and let me know what happens , if you want that data after saving in database retrieve it again and try not to use too much loop, if possible.

Comment: And what you were thinking about using core PHP functions there is no problem the way you have used `json_decode` .Because of this if your plugin is keeping visitor's log, check that may cause slow down of site.

Comment: Another important thing is you are changing the main query and not resetting it consider using `wp_reset_postdata();`.

Comment: in a single function using conditional statement - which conditional statement you are talking about pls ? @PrafullaKumarSahu

Comment: If you are using  different social networks try to use a conditional based on this and do your job in a single function  and have you used  `wp_reset_postdata();` and `wp_footer` and tried , then let me know the result.

Comment: ok understood, let me try it ...@PrafullaKumarSahu

Comment: when am using wp_footer it works very fast but my code isn't working, I added wp_reset_postdata() as well @PrafullaKumarSahu

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92112/discussion-between-prafulla-kumar-sahu-and-aidaghazaryan).

Comment: Alternatively, you can use a schedule event to update the statistics instead of triggering it when using Admin menu. See [wp_schedule_event](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event)

Comment: can you update me on this, please .

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call some function inside your functions.php use the related hook or visit [actions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) and
[filters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference) and also consider checking your templates and find which hook should be used for calling which functions , you if want to modify the output use filter and if you want to perform some action use action.Depending open the job you need to use the hooks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `admin_init`

```
add_action('admin_init', 'setTumblrShares');
```